# SQL order by sorting by first number not by value on a calculated column using Format()

Tags: sql

When i run the below query my results are formatted correctly, but the Total Value column is sorting by the first digit of the value rather than the total value result.  so it is sorting something like this

| Product | Total Value |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 1 |
| Product 2 | 10 |
| Product 3 | 100 |
| Product 4 | 2 |
| Product 5 | 20 |
| product 5 | 200 |
| Product 6 | 3 |
| Product 7 | 30 |
| product 8 | 300 |
| Product 9 | 4 |
| Product 10 | 40 |
| product 11 | 400 |

the Query I have is as below

```
Select 
p.c_Code as 'Product', 
p.c_description as 'Description', 
b.c_code 'Branch', 
format(pbs.c_stocklevel, 'n2') as 'Stock Level', 
Format(pbic.c_averagecost, 'n2') as 'Average Cost', 
Format((pbs.c_Stocklevel * pbic.c_averagecost),'n2') as tv

from t_productbranchstatistics pbs
join t_product p on p.c_id = pbs.c_product
join t_branch b on b.c_id = pbs.c_branch
join t_product_branchinfo pbi on pbi.c__owner_  = p.c_id and pbi.c_branch = b.c_id
join t_product_branchinfo_costings pbic on pbic.c_id = pbi.c_costings
where pbs.c_branch = @[_CurrentBranch._ID]
```

after reading a bit, I'm assuming its because the Format is setting it as a string but when i try to cast its failing and im not sure what im doing wrong :(

Comment: Which DBMS (MS-SQL, mysql, postgres) are you using?
Have you forgotten to add the ORDER BY Clause in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an order by clause: order by pbs.c_Stocklevel * pbic.c_averagecost

Comment: What a dope i didn't even think of that thank you :)